# Trying to measure the length of specific parameter in postman

Tags: postman, postman-testcase

I am newbee and don't have enough experience writing test script in postman. At the moment I am trying to extract length of a specific variable(organizationnumber) for the following response

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "name": "Test1 AB",
            "organizationnumber": "1234566293"
        },
        {
            "name": "Test AB",
            "organizationnumber": "1234564007"
        }
        
    ]
}
```

And I am trying following test script in postman to get length

```
pm.test("organizationnumber length is 10", () => {
  const responseJson = pm.response.json();
  pm.expect(responseJson.organizationnumber).to.have.lengthOf(10);
```

And I am getting following error message for test case:

`organizationnumber length is 10 | AssertionError: Target cannot be null or undefined.`

Answer (score 0):

You need to iterate over the array in the response:

```
const responseJson = pm.response.json();

for (var i = 0; i < responseJson.data.length; i++) {
    let organizationnumber = responseJson.data[i].organizationnumber;

    pm.test("organizationnumber length of " + organizationnumber + " is 10", function () {
        pm.expect(organizationnumber).to.have.lengthOf(10);
    });
}
```